# Will Java app slow down by presence of -Xdebug or only when stepping through code?

Tags: java, debugging

I realize that Java code will [slow down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195720/why-does-java-code-slow-down-in-debugger) when run in debugger.

Question is, will the code slow down simply by starting Java with these options:

```
Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n
```

??

Or does the slowdown only happen when you connect to the "debug port" and actually step through code using an IDE?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, to strictly answer your question - at least as stated in its title - `-Xdebug` only *enables debugging support in the VM* using JVMDI in JVMs prior to 5.0. So in itself, it doesn't do much. Moreover, JVMDI is [deprecated since 5.0](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) in favor of [JVMTI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html):

> -**Xdebug**
>   Start with support for [JVMDI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jvmdi-spec.html) enabled. JVMDI has been deprecated and is not used for debugging in J2SE 5.0, so this option isn't needed for debugging in J2SE 5.0.

So -Xdebug doesn't do anything anymore and the important part is:

```
-Xrunjdwp:<name1>[=<value1>],<name2>[=<value2>]...
```

or, starting with Java 5.0, the newer (that you should prefer as the JDWP agent in 5.0 uses the JVM TI interface to the VM rather than the older JVMDI interface):

```
--agentlib:jdwp=<name1>[=<value1>],<name2>[=<value2>]...
```

Now, to my knowledge, just [loading the jwdp agent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#starting) and/or configuring the JVM to listen
for a socket connection on a given port don't have any noticeable performance impact. But connecting a debugger does.

Comment: Even loading the jwdp agent without attaching a debugger [can have a performance penalty](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/java-performance-when-debugging-is-enabled/).

Comment: There is an opposite opinion https://stackoverflow.com/a/2195731/657723

Answer (score 11):

Performance testing results at AMD indicate that simply enabling the debug agent via the JVM commandline *does* cause performance degradation regardless of having a debugger connected to it, and that the degradation can be quite large depending on the workload:

> Note that we weren’t actually attaching a debugger when we were
>   measuring performance, so we had assumed this agentlib option would be
>   performance-neutral in this usage scenario. When we removed this
>   option, both the CPU utilization and the performance on this workload
>   (measured in requests handled per second) improved dramatically.

See their report:

http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/java-performance-when-debugging-is-enabled/

Above link is dead, here's a web archive link of it: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20160316201129/http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/java-performance-when-debugging-is-enabled/

Comment: When the JVM process runs for long (some days/weeks), slow down is definitely visible. My context: GWT application with Oracle backend, Java 7 on Solaris Zone.

Comment: The AMD article has dropped off the web, but can stil be found in the wayback machine here : https://web.archive.org/web/20160316201129/http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/java-performance-when-debugging-is-enabled/

Answer (score 1):

No, simply enabling the debugging port will have no effect on runtime performance. At least I've never noticed any.

..

Comment: that's not the question he is asking, he's talking about launching the JVM with debug options

Comment: @Valentin - huh? What? Please explain why the command lines don't enable a debug port and hence answer the query.

Comment: ok, seems like I had a sudden case of "shit in my eyes"...@jarnbjo : could you just make a void edit to your answer, so I can remove my downvote ?

Comment: @Valentin No, you didn't, the initial answer was *"The presence of debugging information in the class files will only increase the class file size and has no impact on runtime performance. At least not with current VMs."*. This was not an answer to the question.

Comment: I did in fact misread the question and was a little bit too quick to answer, but edited my answer when I realized my mistake. I'm not sure why the edit does not show though ...

Comment: @jarnbjo, what does trigger the slow down?

Comment: oh ok thanks @Pascal, thought I was hallucinating. Removed the downvote anyway.