# Eclipse Debugging: Turn "Step over" to "Run to next line"

Tags: eclipse, debugging

SO the background to this question can be found here: [Slow Java Debugging Performance in Long-running Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807452/slow-java-debugging-performance-in-long-running-method/54805259#54805259). Essentially what this is sttaing is that using the `Step over` functionality in the (Eclipse) Java Debugger is incredibly slow which is really cumbersome if one just wants to step over a line of code.

A solution to this is to place the cursor into the next line and hit `Ctrl+R` (`Run to Line`) but this is not quite as comfortable as simply hitting a button (like hitting `F6` for stepping over the line).

Therefore my question is whether there is a way to either make the `Step over` command run to the next line instead of whatever it is doing right now or to create a shortcut that places the cursor into the next line and then invokes `Run to Line` automatically so that this functionality is available with a single keystroke as well.

If there is no "default" way of achieving this, does someone know of a plugin that provides such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and it is not easy to implement this, because:

1) There may not be a line at all where the `Run To Line` breakpoint can be put, e.g. if the current line is on a return or throw statement or is the last line in a void method.

2) Even if there is a next line, there are recursive invocations: With `Step over`, the thread is not stopped at the next line in a nested invocation, but with `Run to Line` it is. So the current stack depth would have to be tracked and the thread restarted, which would slow things down again.

3) Similar, Exceptions have to be considered, too, probably by using exception breakpoints for the thread and auto-continuing.

(And, of course, return values cannot be observed.)

But feel free to suggest it as enhancement at https://bugs.eclipse.org